# Adapting functions from Genesis theme

Tags: actions, genesis-theme-framework

I am trying to adapt a tutorial based on the Genesis theme to the Bones starter theme, but am battling with the following functions:

```
add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'tsm_do_acf_form_edit_toggle', 5 );

add_action( 'genesis_after', 'tsm_do_acf_form_content' );
```

I've spent the afternoon trying to google it, and the furtherst I've gotten is:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'tsm_do_acf_form_content' );
```

or

```
add_action( 'init', 'tsm_do_acf_form_content' );
```

but it doesn't work.

What would be the "normal" equivalents? Am I missing something glaringly obvious? The link to the tutorial is:

http://thestizmedia.com/front-end-post-editing-with-acf-pro/

Thanks so much!

Comment: `genesis_entry_header` hook executes before the entry content and generates the entry header content in all loop blocks. `genesis_after hook` executes immediately before the closing tag in the document source.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, thanks for your reply. Would [genesis_after] not then be the same as [wp_head]?

Comment: This is kind of very specific to third party _and_ commercial theme. Could you change your question around to be more generic to WordPress development?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with anything in <head></head>. `genesis_entry_header` is in [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), before the content. `genesis_after` comes after the footer.

Comment: Found out the issue - I had to place the code in functions.php so that it was called before the header